# Using CASE in MERGE statement : ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

Initial Query:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
USING TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
WHEN MATCHED 
 THEN UPDATE SET
   t1.PHONE_NUMBER = t2.PHONE_NUMBER;
```

I need to add another CASE in this:

```
CASE WHEN t1.type in ('A','B') then t2.phone_number
else nvl(t2.phone_number,t1.phone_number)
```

What I have tried to incorporate this :

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
USING TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.ID = t2.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
CASE WHEN t1.type in ('A','B') THEN UPDATE SET t2.phone_number 
ELSE UPDATE SET NVL(t2.phone_number,t1.phone_number)
```

Getting error : ORA-00905: missing keyword .

Can CASE statement be followed by WHEN...THEN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it would be like below

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
USING TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.ID = t2.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET t1.PHONE_NUMBER = CASE 
                          WHEN t1.type in ('A','B') THEN  t2.phone_number 
                          ELSE NVL(t2.phone_number, t1.phone_number)
                        END
```

Comment: Thank you, @Zaynul
Update missing in your query:
WHEN MATCHED THEN "UPDATE" SET.

Also after adding UPDATE, still getting ORA-00905: missing keyword :

NVL(t2.phone_number,t1.phone_number)
                              ^-- error here -- ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Just missing a `END` at the end of the case statement.

Comment: @gooner_psy check the edited answer that was missing end for case